# Why is css style not being applied after transclusion?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Why style is not being applied to 
In following code I am using `ng-transclude`.[Transclusion](https://www.google.com.pk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=transclusion) works fine, only problem is that class `.box` is not being applied to `span`. Why is that so?

**`transclude.html`** is:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <script src="js/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/transclude.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            .box{
               background-color: red; 
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div sidebox title="Links">
            <ul>
                <li>first link</li>
                <li>2nd link</li>
            </ul>
        </div>        
    </body>
</html>
```

**`transclude.js`** is:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.directive('sidebox',function(){
    return {
      restrict:'A',
      transclude:true,
      scope:{
          title:'@'
      },
      template:'<div>\n\
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>\n\
        <span class="box" ng-transclude></span></div>\n\
'
    };
});
```

**UPDATE:**
From source it's clear that `.box` was applied but it did not turn `div` red.
[image]

Comment: The span doesn't appear to have any content. How can you tell what background colour it has?

Comment: @Quentin As I have added `.box` in style tag so I think it should have `red` background.

Comment: Yes, that much is obvious. I asked how you could tell that it does not (since it doesn't seem to have any content)

Comment: @Quentin Please, have a look at updated part of question.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. A `<ul>` is not permitted inside a `<span>`. Write valid HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `<span>` element is by default `display: inline`. That means that it only accepts plain or marked up text, not other elements, and especially not `display: block` elements such as `<ul>`.

If you really want to use a span (you should use a div), you need to set its css to `display: block` for it to resize itself according to block content. Or `display: inline-block` if you want some other (inline) properties while retaining the block behavior. But `inline-block` has some side effects you most likely don't want.

Also this is not an angular problem, as it is just a plain html/css problem.